# Proof of Elapsed Time Susceptible to Random number generator attack?

Tags: consensus

Since Proof of Elapsed Time (POET) uses a Random Wait time to elect a leader, would it be susceptible to Random number generator attack?

Nathan Aw

Comment: Bitcoin Stack Exchange on topic seems to have changed; sorry if migrated incorrectly.

Comment: True random number generation is difficult (unless random number generators have improved?) and many can be seeded, some bad ones producing predictable results with careful seeding. So, as I understand it the question becomes, what random number generation system is uesd, who controls it (how is it accessed?) and, how is it seeded? An attack that is theoretically possible is not necessarily feasible.